# Exoplayer Buffer state freezes the UI?

Tags: android, service, exoplayer

I am working on an online radio android application using Exoplayer.

In my `PlayerActiivity` in `onCreate()` method I initialize the `media browser` which starts a `Music service`.

```
public class PlayerActiivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   initMediaBrowser();
}

protected void initMediaBrowser(){
   // Connect a media browser to get the media session token.
   mediaBrowser = new MediaBrowserCompat(this, new ComponentName(this, 
                MusicService.class), connectionCallback, null);
   }
}
```

The Music service extends `MediaBrowserServiceCompat`

```
public class MusicService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat {

@Override public void onCreate() {...}

@Override public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {...}

...
}
```

When a user chooses some radio station the `handlePlayRequest` method from `PlaybackManager` class is called:

```
public class PlaybackManager implements Playback.Callback {

  public void handlePlayRequest() {
     serviceCallback.onPlaybackStart();
     playback.play(currentTrack);
  }
}
```

The method `onPlaybackStart` sets the media session to active state and restarts the service *(as MusicService is already created, the `onStartCommand` is only called)*.

```
public void onPlaybackStart() {
 session.setActive(true);

 delayedStopHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

 // The service needs to continue running even after the bound client (usually a
 // MediaController) disconnects, otherwise the music playback will stop.
 // Calling startService(Intent) will keep the service running until it is explicitly killed.
 startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MusicService.class));
}
```

Method `play` gets the current music Track and prepares the player for playing:

```
@Override
public void play(QueueItem item) {
   playOnFocusGain = true;
   tryToGetAudioFocus();
   registerAudioNoisyReceiver();
   String mediaId = item.getDescription().getMediaId();
   boolean mediaHasChanged = !TextUtils.equals(mediaId, currentMediaId);
   if (mediaHasChanged) {
       currentMediaId = mediaId;
       if(mediaProvider != null){
           mediaProvider.setCurrentPlayerMediaId(currentMediaId);
       }
       LogHelper.d(TAG, "change current mediaId to: " + mediaId);
   }

   if (mediaHasChanged || exoPlayer == null) {
       releaseResources(false); // release everything except the player

       Track track = null;
       if(mediaProvider != null){
           track = mediaProvider.getTrack(item.getDescription().getMediaId());
       }

       String source;

       if(track == null){
           if (callback != null) {
               callback.onError("Player error " + " track with media id: " + item.getDescription().getMediaId() + " was not found");
           }
           LogHelper.e(TAG, "Player error " + " track with media id: " + item.getDescription().getMediaId() + " was not found");
           return;
       }
       source = track.getStreamUrl();

       if (source != null) {
          source = source.replaceAll(" ", "%20"); // Escape spaces for URLs
       }

       if (exoPlayer == null) {

           DefaultAllocator allocator =
               new DefaultAllocator(true, C.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);

           DefaultLoadControl defaultLoadControl = new DefaultLoadControl(
               allocator,
               MIN_BUFFER_MS,
               MAX_BUFFER_MS,
               DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_MS,
               DEFAULT_BUFFER_FOR_PLAYBACK_AFTER_REBUFFER_MS,
               DEFAULT_TARGET_BUFFER_BYTES,
               DEFAULT_PRIORITIZE_TIME_OVER_SIZE_THRESHOLDS
               );

           exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
               new DefaultRenderersFactory(context),
               new DefaultTrackSelector(), defaultLoadControl);
           exoPlayer.addListener(eventListener);
       }

       final AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
           .setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
           .setUsage(USAGE_MEDIA)
           .build();

       exoPlayer.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes);

       // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
       DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory =
               new DefaultDataSourceFactory(
                   context, Util.getUserAgent(context,
                   context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)), null);

       MediaSource mediaSource;
       if (track.isHlsStream()) {
           mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(
               Uri.parse(source));
       } else {
           mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(
               Uri.parse(source));
       }

       // Prepares media to play (happens on background thread) and triggers
       // {@code onPlayerStateChanged} callback when the stream is ready to play.
       exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);

       // If we are streaming from the internet, we want to hold a
       // Wifi lock, which prevents the Wifi radio from going to
       // sleep while the song is playing.
       wifiLock.acquire();
   }

   configurePlayerState();
}
```

Method `configurePlayerState` starts to play media content:

```
private void configurePlayerState() {
   LogHelper.d(TAG, "configurePlayerState. currentAudioFocusState=", currentAudioFocusState);
   if (currentAudioFocusState == AUDIO_NO_FOCUS_NO_DUCK) {
       // We don't have audio focus and can't duck, so we have to pause
       pause();
   } else {
       registerAudioNoisyReceiver();

       if (currentAudioFocusState == AUDIO_NO_FOCUS_CAN_DUCK) {
           // We're permitted to play, but only if we 'duck', ie: play softly
           exoPlayer.setVolume(VOLUME_DUCK);
       } else {
           exoPlayer.setVolume(VOLUME_NORMAL);
       }

       // If we were playing when we lost focus, we need to resume playing.
       if (playOnFocusGain) {
           LogHelper.d("LocalPlayback", "PLAY!");
           exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
           playOnFocusGain = false;
           if(!mediaProvider.isTrackPlayed()){
               callback.onTrackPlayed(true);
           }
       }
   }
}
```

After `configurePlayerState` executing the Exoplayer goes to the buffering state.

Method `onPlayerStateChanged` is called with `playbackState == Player.STATE_BUFFERING`

```
public final class LocalPlayback implements Playback {
@Override
        public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
            switch (playbackState) {
                case Player.STATE_IDLE:
                case Player.STATE_BUFFERING:
                case Player.STATE_READY:
                    if (callback != null) {
                        callback.onPlaybackStatusChanged(getState());
                    }
                    break;
                case Player.STATE_ENDED:
                    // The media player finished playing the current song.
                    if (callback != null) {
                        callback.onCompletion();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

}
```

Right after the Exoplayer goes to Buffering the UI freezes. On my Motorola (Moto X Play) and Nexus (Nexus 5X) devices the freeze lasts about ~3 seconds. On client devices the freeze lasts even more.

Only after callback `onPlayerStateChanged` is called with `playbackState == Player.STATE_READY` the UI freeze ends.

> Question: **How to avoid the freeze of UI while exoplayer stays in Buffering state?**

My dependencies:

```
android {
 compileSdkVersion 27
 defaultConfig {
   applicationId "com.app"
   minSdkVersion 16
   targetSdkVersion 27
   multiDexEnabled true
   buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
 }

 buildTypes {
   ...
 }

 compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 }
}

dependencies {
 ...
 compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.7.3'
 compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.7.3'  
}
```

Comment: Having a similar issue. Did you ever resolve your problem?